# Function of return type vector and enum class

Tags: c++, function, vector, enums, return-type

```
enum class State {kEmpty, kObstacle};
```

For this enum class what does it mean to use State as return type in vector.
If the function is supposed to return vector .

```
vector<State> ParseLine(string line) {
    istringstream sline(line);
    int n;
    char c;
    // TODO: Change the variable type for row
    // to be a vector<State>
    vector<State> row;
    while (sline >> n >> c && c == ',') {
      // TODO: Modify the line below to push_back
      // a State::kEmpty if n is 0, and push_back
      // a State::kObstacle otherwise.
      if(n==0)
      row.push_back(State::kEmpty);
      else 
        row.push_back(State::kObstacle);
    }
    return row;
}
```

Like, here Parse line function return a vector quantity that's ok.
But why and when should we mention enum class(State) in vector return type of function like this

```
vector<***State***> ParseLine(string line)
```

In what conditions we should use an enum object in a vector as an return type of functions.

Comment: `vector<State>` is the type of the return value. What's not clear about that?

Comment: previously there was the return type as vector<int> but now as i have declared an enum i want the function to be able to pick and return enum values.So. here State is a enum class object.I want to know in what conditions ,do we have to use an enum object in  a vector as a return type of function.@super

Comment: I still don't understand your question. You need to use a vector with an enum class if you want to return a vector with an enum class... ? If you want to return a vector with int you would use that. What exactly are you asking?